# libGDX: does the player make like on the facebook page or not?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, libgdx

I built a new libGDX project using `gdx-facebook` extension as shown:
[image]

Then I read this article [gdx-facebook/wiki](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook/wiki), but I don't know how I detect the player make `like` on the game page or not? because I want to reward him for this action